# how to pass qmap from qt to javascript?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qmap

I could not find the sample code about passing qmap to javascript in qt.

what I did ?

I have connected a QObject to the javascript, and could able to emit the signal from qt app, which 
is captured by javascript.

```
emit mydata(mapVariable);
```

In JavaScript:
 in the alert I am trying to print like:

```
function myslot(mapVar) {
    alert (" map variable " + mapVar);
 }
```

Problem:

It is not printing anything. That shows fundamentally I am making a big blunder here. Kindly suggest me how to resolve this issue?..

Comment: What exactly do you plan to do with a QMap in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

I found the solution, The QVariantMap is the data structure which can be passed to the java script, and can be treated as a JSON in the java script side.

Comment: At least for me passing a `QVariantMap` to Javascript does not work.